# Combining CreateProcess and AllowSetForegroundWindow on WIN32

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, focus, createprocess

I have an application that is essentially a "helper" application that wraps another app.

The app that the user interacts with is a process that is created by the "helper" app like so:

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
STARTUPINFO startupInfo;
memset(&processInfo, 0, sizeof(processInfo));
memset(&startupInfo, 0, sizeof(startupInfo));
startupInfo.hStdInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
startupInfo.hStdOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
startupInfo.hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
startupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
int retval = CreateProcess(cmd, cmdLine, NULL, NULL, false,
    CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo,
    &processInfo);
```

This process is an executable that I do not have the source code to and cannot make changes to.

The "helper" application does a few things based mainly on network traffic from the other app.  At one point I want to display a file browse dialog from the helper app based on something the user does in the started UI process.

When I show the file dialog from the helper app, it's shown behind the UI of the process that was created, which isn't ideal.  I tried calling SetForegroundWindow() from the helper app but it fails the criteria specified for SetForegroundWindow in the MSDN docs ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ), namely:

The process is not the foreground process.

The process was not started by the foreground process.

(even though the process created the foreground process).

Is there a way to call CreateProcess() with a flag or setting that works like calling AllowSetForegroundWindow() from that process?  Or a flag that can be used to make Windows think the started process is "the same" as the process that started it for purposes of SetForegroundWindow permissions?

Or is there another way I can show the dialog generated by the helper app on top of the created process' dialogs?

Comment: If the operating system allowed your app to be special by allowing it to effectively steal focus from other apps, then all other apps would have the same capability.  This is an arms race, and Microsoft has wisely taken steps to prevent it.

Comment: My app is special.  It is the one that *started* the other app.

Comment: Would it make sense to create your window with the 3rd party process's window as its owner/parent? Your window will then be on top of their window. (This isn't a universal solution: If their window might close at any moment, or not be open at all sometimes, or you don't have a good way to find the right window... It also ties the input queues of the two processes/threads together, which isn't great but shouldn't be an issue if things are simple.) --- Failing that, maybe you could kludge things by making your window always-on-top. Not ideal, but I'm not sure anything will be.

Comment: @JasonChampion - The ability to call `CreateProcess` does not make your process special, any process can do that.  Put more plainly, if the process that you are starting isn't designed to have focus shift back to its parent process, then requesting the ability to modify the behavior of the child process would be a request to do something special (which is possible after all using `CreateRemoteThread`), and an all around horrible idea.

Comment: I ultimately ended up combining the two and using the "helper" app as a DLL plugin. Separate executables for things is just a big hassle to be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could think of off the top of my head would be to do remote thread injection into the child process, and then have your injected thread call `AllowSetForegroundWindow` with the appropriate parameters to allow the parent process to steal foreground-ness back.

I have not tested this though.